# 1st Python file creation in Notepad on Windows getting error

Tags: python, windows, cmd, command, notepad

So I've read through countless people asking similar questions but none seemed to be the answer I was needing.

Tonight I started the W3 Python tutorial. I downloaded the latest version of Python.

The first task is to go into a text editor, in this case I chose Notepad. I copied the following:

print("Hello World!")

and saved that as helloworld.py

I made sure it was in my C: drive... which is the only one I have anyway.

I used cmd.exe and typed in C:\Users\MyName>python helloworld.py

And I get the error: python: can't open file 'C:\Users\18327\helloworld.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory

It is saving into my documents folder, is that the issue?

Comment: you need to run it with the full path to the python file, or relative from where you are running it .... if you `cd Documents` then you can probably run it fine or if you give the full path `python C:\Users\18327\Documents\helloworld.py`  ... you can always make sure its right by typing `dir C:\Users\18327\Documents\helloworld.py` if its not there it will throw an error

Answer (score 0):

Your file's directory is 'C:\Users\18327\Documents\helloworld.py', while your directory specified in cmd is 'C:\Users\18327\helloworld.py'. Instead, run cmd in the Documents folder.